# How to keep session alive across multiple tab if one of the tab is active and make it die if all tab is inactivity

Tags: asp.net, session-timeout

The user is accessing the website and opened multiple tab.

**The session should keep alive when:**
Any of the tab is active (mouse move & key strokes on keyboard).

**The session should die and redirect to login page automatically when:**
All the tabs is inactivity (no mouse move, no key strokes)

Can you please hint me how to do this?

Comment: I hope you realize that the server has no idea about tabs, right?

Answer (score 0):

It's a dirty solution, and I haven't tried it yet, but this could work in theory:

1. When you have detected activity on the page, save a flag in a database table to denote that there is activity on the page (probably also want the timestamp to help you determine how long ago the activity happened and the user identifier to make sure it's the right session). Depending on how often you want to make this save, you could use a simple script like this (https://stackoverflow.com/a/3877867/987905) to keep track of the most recent keystroke or whatever you want to track, then after a certain amount of time (say 5 minutes), decide to save it to a database if there ever was activity (that way you aren't making database saves every time there is activity detection).
2. During your check to see if the session is active, check the database for the flag and timestamp to see if the session has been reported as alive on any instances of that user being logged in. If so, re-activate the session via your keep alive, or re-authenticate.

Again, I haven't tried this, but have been thinking about it recently. It seems to be a viable solution, just comes with the downside of making database saves/calls behind the scenes, possibly hurting performance.